# Can cracking fingers cause Arthritis?

Tags: joints

I have been cracking my fingers for 2-3 years and on the first year I was told that I'm going to get arthritis because of it.

I've been researching this since the first year and I've never gotten an answer. Most people say either Yes, No or I don't know.

Arthritis is mainly cause by bones rubbing together and cracking fingers is just air sockets poping.

I've asked my biology teacher and he said that he's not sure. He then explained to me that the cracking sound from people cracking their fingers is just air sockets poping.

So can finger cracking cause arthritus?

Comment: I believe this has been answered on [skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/is-popping-your-knuckles-bad-for-you)

Comment: Thanx @RoryM I think your link answers my question. So in conclusion, Cracking your fingers causes some harm but it's so negligible it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Similar: http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/19850/6422

Comment: @Cornelius It is similar but it doesn't answer my question. Sorry for the reeeaaallly late answer. Although I did get the answer that I was looking for from http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/is-popping-your-knuckles-bad-for-you